# Unable to identify formula error

Tags: python, math

just started to learn how to use python and I'm unsure where to ask if I'm unable to identify what is going wrong with my program, if this is the wrong forum then could someone please direct me to the correct one. It's a calculator designed to give the 3 angles of a triangle when all three lengths are inputted. It seems to work in terms of coding but all 3 angles are identical when they shouldn't be. It's best explained if you run the code below and you'll see what I'm talking about. Also working out the type of triangle is abit dodgy however I'm sure this is an error on my part which when closely looked at will resolve itself.

```
import math

#degrees = (180/pi).radians (python maths works in radians) & radians = (pi/180).degrees

print("Welcome to the tri-angle calculator, please ensure that all 3 length inputs form a triangle otherwise program will not function. They must also be converted to the same units of length")

a = int(input("Insert first length of triangle in degrees: "))
b = int(input("Insert second length of triangle in degrees: "))
c = int(input("Insert third length of triangle in degrees: "))
#length inputs

A = math.acos(((b ** 2) + (c ** 2) - (a ** 2)) / (2 * b * c))
B = math.acos(((a ** 2) + (c ** 2) - (b ** 2)) / (2 * a * c))
C = math.acos(((a ** 2) + (b ** 2) - (c ** 2)) / (2 * a * b))
#working out all 3 angles of triangles

if(a == c and b == c):
    type = "Equilateral Triangle"
elif(math.cos(A) == 0 or math.cos(B) == 0 or math.cos(C) == 0):
    type = "Right Angle Triangle"
elif((a == b and c != b) or (b == c and c == a) or (c == a and c != b)):
    type = "Isoceles Triangle"
elif(a != b and b != c and c != a and A < (0.5 * math.pi) and B < (0.5 * math.pi) and C < (0.5 * math.pi)):
    type = "Acute Triangle"
else:
    type = "Obtuse Triangle"
#Working out the triangle type

print("The order of which the angles are shown in are opposite to the length inputted:")
print("Angle A - " + str((180 / math.pi) * A))
print("Angle B - " + str((180 / math.pi) * A))
print("Angle C - " + str((180 / math.pi) * A))

print("And it's a " + type )
#Printing Results

exit()
```

Comment: Look carefully at what you're printing (the last 5 lines)

Comment: Note: you're not checking if the `a`, `b`, `c` numbers can actually be a triangle. Also, length doesn't measure in degrees. HAHAHAHA, good one @user3080953!

Comment: Very confusing to put the comments that say what a block of code is doing *after* the block instead of before it.

Comment: Also double-check you isoceles tests. BTW, testing if 3 lengths make a valid triangle is very easy. It's called the triangle inequality. Your calculator program should do that.

Comment: Try to never name something ``type`` (or any other reserved keyword).
keywords: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords
builtins: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: The 3 angles are identical since you print three times the angle A (see end of the three print statements "Angle X". Probably just a typical copy & paste error :-)

Answer (score 1):

The program, fixed, and in a function (not necessarily the best one, but that can give you ideas :) )

```
import math

#degrees = (180/pi).radians (python maths works in radians) & radians = (pi/180).degrees

print("Welcome to the tri-angle calculator, please ensure that all 3 length inputs form a triangle otherwise program will not function. They must also be converted to the same units of length")


def magic_in_progress(a, b, c):
    A = math.acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2) / (2 * b * c))
    B = math.acos((a**2 + c**2 - b**2) / (2 * a * c))
    C = math.acos((a**2 + b**2 - c**2) / (2 * a * b))
    #working out all 3 angles of triangles

    name = "Undetermined Triangle"

    pi_over_2 = 0.5 * math.pi

    if a == b == c:
        name = "Equilateral Triangle"
    elif 0 in (math.cos(A), math.cos(B), math.cos(C)):
        name = "Right Angle Triangle"
    elif a == b != c or b == c != a or c == a != b:
        name = "Isoceles Triangle"
    elif a != b != c != a and A < pi_over_2 and B < pi_over_2 and C < pi_over_2:
        name = "Acute Triangle"
    else:
        name = "Obtuse Triangle"
    #Working out the triangle type

    print("The order of which the angles are shown in are opposite to the length inputted:")
    print(f"Angle A - {180 / math.pi * A}")
    print(f"Angle B - {180 / math.pi * B}")
    print(f"Angle C - {180 / math.pi * C}")

    return name

#length inputs
a = int(input("Insert first length of triangle: "))
b = int(input("Insert second length of triangle: "))
c = int(input("Insert third length of triangle: "))

triangle_type = magic_in_progress(a, b, c)

print(f"And it's a {triangle_type}")
```

And when used:

```
>>> a = int(input("Insert first length of triangle: "))
Insert first length of triangle: 4
>>> b = int(input("Insert second length of triangle: "))
Insert second length of triangle: 5
>>> c = int(input("Insert third length of triangle: "))
Insert third length of triangle: 6
>>> triangle_type = magic_in_progress(a, b, c)
The order of which the angles are shown in are opposite to the length inputted:
Angle A - 41.40962210927086
Angle B - 55.771133672187425
Angle C - 82.81924421854173
>>> print(f"And it's a {triangle_type}")
And it's a Acute Triangle
```

Comment: Indeed, I did not check the formulas.

Comment: @PM2Ring Just fixed them and cleaned them to make them more pythonic.
Can be useful for anyone who might read it later.